# If $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ is convergent, then discuss the convergence or divergence of the following series.

Tags: real-analysis

> If $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ is convergent then discuss the convergence or divergence of the following series whose $n^{th}$ term is
>
> - $ a_n \sin n $
> - $\displaystyle \frac {a_n}{1+| a_n |}$

If $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ is absolutely convergent then then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin n $ and $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {a_n}{1+|a_n|} $ are convergent. But what if $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ is conditionally convergent. 
 A little hint would be appreciated. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: @suchandaadhikari try $a_n = \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$, and you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805521/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac-left-sin-leftn-right-rightn-converge/2805531#2805531) for the proof that $\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$ doesn't converge

Comment: @ jakobian thank you so much  ..nice example. .can u give a hint about the 2nd series. .

Comment: I think other series is convergent as both have same nature as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: If you please elaborate a little more...

Comment: @Jakobian Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost it's not a full answer though.