# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(n)/\sqrt n$ converge absolutely?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

So I already proved that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt n}
$$
conditionally converges using the Dirichlet test.

I'm almost sure it doesn't converges absolutely, but I'm struggling with proving it using cauchy condition or with other convergence tests.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805521 might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{\sin^2n}{\sqrt{n}} \leqslant \frac{|\sin n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}$, assuming that $\displaystyle \sum_{n＝1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin n|}{\sqrt{n}} < \infty$ would entail that $\displaystyle \sum_{n＝1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2n}{\sqrt{n}} <  \infty$.

However, as $\sin^2n＝\frac{1-\cos(2n)}{2}$ one notices that:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n＝1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2n}{\sqrt{n}}＝\displaystyle\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}－\displaystyle\sum_{n＝1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2n)}{2\sqrt{n}}.$$
Can you see why this would end up entailing a contradiction?